# C++ virtual function and design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have an abstract base class for Data type and two inherited class, Data1 and Data2. Data1 and Data2 have different members. I have an abstract class Proc which operates on these data. Proc has a virtual function update which takes a reference of Data as parameter. Proc1 and Proc2 both define its own implementation. However both of the implementation will use members defined in concrete class Data1 and Data2. How to make this work given the parameter is a reference of Data? For example.

```
class Data {};
class Data1: public Data{
    int x;
};
class Data2: public Data{
    string str;
};

class Proc{
    virtual void update(const Data&) = 0;
};

class Proc1: public Proc{
    update(const Data &d){
         // this does not work
         cout << x << endl;
    }
};

class Proc2: public Proc{
    update(const Data &d){
         // this does not work
         cout << str << endl;
    }
};
```

Thank you for suggestions.

**Update:**

Maybe my issue is it's not always a good idea to define an abstract base type Data for the sake of polymorphism which Derived classes have little in common(except conceptually).
It might be easier to extend the Proc class which deals with new concrete Data type in the future?

My proc class actually serves as a container for Data, which is a map of Id and deque. As you can see, it's not a good solution to provide virtual update function inside Data. Because update is more related with Proc (calculation does based on concrete Data type though).

Comment: Unrelated note, base types should have virtual destructors, pretty much always.

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks, code's just for illustration purpose

Comment: If you want to use a base class, then define some functionality that will be implemented in the subclasses. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to have a base class. Abstract base classes with concrete derived classes are at the core of polymorphism, however polymorphism means making use of the functionality that is common among all subclasses (well common at the declaration level rather than the implementation level).

Comment: The only question is see is "doesn't work". Based on what I am looking at it doesn't compile. But I sense you want more. See other posts on polymorphism and visitor. Both will work to overcome your compiler erro

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a pure virtual method in `Data` called `update`. Then implement it in `Data1` and `Data2`. One of the primary goals of object oriented programming is to keep the data and code that is related to it together :).

Comment: I updated with details. what if concrete update needs info which data does not have, but contained in Proc class?

Comment: @bbc: Then the `Proc` class will have to pass it to the `update` function.  There are other ways, but they're complex, and ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dynamic_cast` should do the job.

```
class Proc1 : public Proc {
    void update(const Data &d) {
       Data1 const* data1Ptr = dynamic_cast<Data1 const*>(&d);
       assert(data1Ptr != NULL);
       // Now use data1Ptr
    }
};
```

Similarly for `Proc2`.

Comment: This works, but a better solution would probably be to fix his nonsensical design pattern

Comment: @dwcanillas I knew it's a bad design. what is the normal design for this? Thank you!

Comment: @dwcanillas, it's not always possible to avoid downcast. It's possible that the OP has presented a simplistic view of his classes.

Comment: @bbc It's hard to say what a good design would be without more detail.  Adam's solution seems like a good one for just the information we have here.

Answer (score 1):

The action that you perform depends on 2 runtime types - that's a case handled by [Double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) mechanism. You may want to check out the Visitor pattern.